# How can I print to a printer with one line of code from terminal?

Tags: terminal

Is there a way to print to a printer on your network with one line of code from the terminal? I was thinking of using telnet to do this. For example, assuming my printer's local IP is 192.168.1.8, piping the message that is to be printed to the command

```
telnet 192.168.1.8 9100
```

would probably work. I just don't know the right way to go about doing it. Any suggestions? And I do know that any text that I would enter after executing above command would print to the printer, but my whole problem is that I need to do it in a single line of code.

Comment: If you found the answer to be useful, please vote.

Answer (score 0):

From Windows consider this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/420149/how-can-i-copy-a-print-file-to-a-networked-printer) and from Linux consider [CUPS](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulpr.htm).

You may test your printer. Learn how [here](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN284354/testing-the-network-connection-of-your-printer-using-the-telnet-command?lang=EN) and you could echo back a line to the printer but your printer would most likely need to support telnet.

Comment: Are you sure that there's no way to use telnet? If I could use telnet the program I'm trying to make would be much more versatile.

Comment: In order to use telnet you need to identify the printer, driver and protocol in order to send the appropriately formatted request. Recommending `lpr` in the answer would provide that formatted request for you and satisfy you need to execute using one line. Of course, you would like to make sure `lpr` is installed. See here for more information on [protocol](https://www.cups.org/doc/network.html). You may test your printer using telnet. See this [video](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN284354/testing-the-network-connection-of-your-printer-using-the-telnet-command?lang=EN)

Answer (score 0):

Where x is the message and y is the local printer IP:

```
echo x | telnet y 9100
```